# Questions About CV's and Resumes

Tags: discussion

I've seen a few questions about CV's or Resumes.  They generally are something like:

> How can I improve this sentence for my resume?  "I come to seeks opportunity, and am of bold character, for to have success in all of the goals I desire."  Help me with seeks/seek and maybe "strong" instead of "bold"?

I think we do a disservice by answering such questions.  We can help someone with fundamental issues with language, but a CV/Resume is a specialized document related to very important outcomes.

If a person asks to make a CV sentence sound better, I get this grating feeling that I don't want to help someone fix a sentence that shouldn't be going into a CV in the first place.  Removing grammatical mistakes in something like this simply assures that trash cans get filled with more grammatically correct CV's.

Answer (score 3):

Tough call here. On one hand, the Stack Exchange is supposed to be about helping to solve ["actual problems that you face"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and it's hard for me to come up with a better example of an "actual problem" than a sentence on a resumé.

On the other hand, I agree with you, and your questions brought to mind several legal disclaimers I've seen throughout the years, such as, "Please consult with your doctor," or "We are not a legal firm."

I wouldn't be in favor of closing questions simply because they are asking about a sentence on a draft CV. However, thanks to your question, I might consider appending one of my answers with a footnote, one that goes something like this:

> I'm only addressing the language question you have asked here, and the alternatives I've provided are not necessarily the best sentences to include in a resumé or CV. We can answer questions about English, but you may want a professional career counselor to review your finished product. We cannot do that for you here; proofreading on ELL is considered off-topic.

Moreover, those who come here for advice should keep that in mind. We will answer an English question, even if that question stems from a line on your resumé, but we are **not** here to help you polish your resumé and get it ready for distribution.